# SharePoint online taxonomy: nested term sets?

Tags: sharepoint-online, taxonomy, term-set

I'm in a job rush, so really got no time to search for this answer in SP.Taxonomy, then I posted this straightforward question-answer pair:

Does Taxonomy accepts nested term sets?

PS: It's also a piece of knowledge contribution to this community, imho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, Taxonomies are built like the following:

- Taxonomy

  - Group

    - TermSet

      - Term

        - Term

Terms however can contain subterms